# MVC For Each loop on a multi level object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, api, foreach

I have the following JSON:

```
{
"row2": {
    "Activity_log_key": 2,
    "Activity_day": "2017-01-12T00:00:00",
    "Effort": 8.0,
    "Comment": "comment text",
    "Activity": "activity text",
    "Work_group": "Project",
    "Work_item": "test project 1",
    "Related_category": {
        "Project_phase": [
            ["category_name", "Design"],
            ["category_key", 116255]
        ]
    }
},
"row3": {
    "Activity_log_key": 3,
    "Activity_day": "2017-01-12T00:00:00",
    "Effort": 5.5,
    "Comment": "no comments",
    "Activity": "activty demo text",
    "Work_group": "Project",
    "Work_item": "project 2",
    "Related_category": {
        "Project_phase": [
            ["category_name", "Develop"],
            ["category_key", 116256]
        ],
        "Training_provider": [
            ["category_name", "Analysis"],
            ["category_key", 116254]
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I convert that JSON response to an object in the controller:

```
Dim client As New HttpClient
Dim request = client.GetStringAsync(url & "/effort")
request.Wait()
Dim response = request.Result
Dim jsonObj As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(response)
ViewData("response") = jsonObj
```

Now I  try to run a `For Each` loop on `ViewData("response")` in the view but I have no results.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You should deserialize into a proper class instead of Object. There's not much that is going to be copied in an Object.

Comment: can you write down a demo class please

Comment: @bassemaiad, the_lotus means is the properties in your json would be properties in a class. For example `public MyClass { public int Activity_log_key {get; set; } // more properties, apologies I use C# not VB }`

Comment: @bassemaiad actually, if you're using Visual Studio, you can create an empty class file, go to `Edit` in the top toolbar menu, then `Paste Special` and `JSON as Classes`. Assuming your JSON is valid it'll create classes based off of your JSON.